# How to show Created By and Modified By columns as lookup field?

Tags: lookup-column

When I want to add a lookup column to a document library, created by and modified by columns are not listed. Can I add these columns to another list or document library as lookup column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These fields are both of type `Person or Group`. This field type is already an (inherited) lookup field (for the user list), and such it is not supported in a 2nd lookup field. See threads [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/eb4429ed-b8aa-4dcb-bada-1a6427417e92/how-to-lookup-person-or-group-field-from-other-list) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56745/is-it-possible-to-make-a-lookup-column-that-looks-up-person-or-group-type-from). The second link contains a workaround via code, but I don't think it is a very good idea, as changes in the user list won't be refelcted in the 2nd linked list.